# Hammer Editor: Ambient_Generic playing alternative sound

Tags: source-engine, half-life-2, hammer

In my Hammer map, I have an ambient_generic sound that plays a certain male citizen phrase, which is then set to output (sound source) at a npc_citizen. The problem is, some voicelines seem to have an alternative sound. I noticed this for the CP "Pick up that can [Nag]" sound - he had at least two different ways of saying it.

Sure, I could put up with that, but the problem comes in when this alternative phrase is from another gender. That npc_citizen I mentioned above has a sound that plays through him, however, when he is scripted to speak, he might say it in a female's voice. The same thing happens to another male citizen. Pretty funny at first, but now it's annoying (from a developer's perspective).

What's the dealio with the ambient_generic having two different sounds for the one actual sound? Should I use another entity to emit speech for a NPC? I did some research, but the rest appeared to be obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hit oil: If you go into the sound browser and set the "Sound Type" to "Raw", you're gonna get more sounds than you ever thought there was. I typed in "metro", and it took me about half an hour to go through all the sounds. Then I typed in "combine", and it looks like it's the same deal.

For citizens, it seems like every phrase has a sound spoken by a male and by a female.